# Get XElements List of XElements List from XML document using linq to xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I create a list of node object:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ListNode : List<Node> {  }
```

And i have an xml document :

```
<details>
<detail>
  <node>
    <key>xxx</key>
    <value>111</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <key>yyy</key>
    <value>222</value>
  </node>
</detail>
<detail>
  <node>
    <key>zzz</key>
    <value>333</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <key>aaa</key>
    <value>444</value>
  </node>
</detail>
</details>
```

what i want to do is to put these xml elements to a List of ListNode objects using linq to xml:

```
<node> => Node Object
<detail> => ListNode
<details> => List<ListNode>
```

this is my linq to xml request:

```
List<ListNode> listNodeDetails = xElement
    .Element("details")
    .Elements("detail")
    .Elements("node")
    .Select(n => new Node() 
        { Key = n.Element("key").Value, 
          Value = n.Element("node").Element("value").Value 
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What's the question?  Are you getting an error, or the wrong results?  If so, please include the error or the results you are getting.

Comment: I want to recuperate xml nodes to a list of ListNode object

Comment: Are there more than one <details> elements contained in the xml? It is only in this case that it makes sense to have a List of ListNode elements.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos The example has multiple detail nodes.  That's how I belive the OP is separating the nodes into separate `ListNode`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you don't really need the `Node` or `ListNode` classes.  You should be able to get the same results using `KeyValuePair<string,string>` (or `Tuple<string,string>`) and `List<KeyValuePari<string,string>>`  (or `List<Tuple<string,string>>`).  Here's how you can get your desired results as a `List<List<KeyValuePair>>`

```
var results =
    element.Elements("detail")
            .Select(
                x =>
                    x.Elements("node")
                    .Select(n => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                        n.Element("key").Value, 
                        n.Element("value").Value))
                    .ToList())
            .ToList();
```

The trick here is that you have an inner linq statement that builds up the `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` while the outer linq statement builds that up into the `List<List<KeyValuePair>>`.  Also you have to use `Elements` instead of `Element` to get a colleciton of all the desired elements.

It's trivial to substitute in your `Node` class (or `Tuple<string,string>`).  But it's a little more difficult, and unnecessary, to substitute in your `ListNode` class.

However here is how you can get a `List<ListNode>` as you currently have the `ListNode` class defined.

```
List<ListNode> list = new List<ListNode>();
foreach (var detail in element.Elements("detail"))
{
    var nodeList = new ListNode();
    nodeList.AddRange(
        detail.Elements("node")
            .Select(
                n => new Node
                {
                    Key = n.Element("key").Value,
                    Value = n.Element("value").Value
                }));
    list.Add(nodeList);
}
```

Here you have to create a `ListNode` before adding the nodes versus using the `ToList` extension method.  You could make that `foreach` into a linq expression, but I typically avoid lambdas that have multiple statements whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You've not really said where you're stuck... Anyway, this should do the trick.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");

var listNodeDetails = xdoc.Root
    .Elements("detail")
    .Elements("node").Select(
        n => new Node
        {
            Key = n.Element("key").Value,
            Value = n.Element("value").Value
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: This results in a `List<Node>` when the OP wants a `List<NodeList>` which is really just a `List<List<Node>>`.  Basically the OP wants the nodes in different detail elements to be in separate lists.

Comment: i dont want a list of node, but a list of listNode class, like i shown below, a listNode class is list of node class, imagine that listNode class correspond to a line and node class correspond to a column